# If null value in a Column A, then how to return the value of column B, and if also B is null, then how to move to the value of C

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grouping, union

Have a table in Google Big Query with date, id and store columns where the goal is to keep track how many stores a customer has visited:

```
|A_date |A_id|Store 1|B_date |B_id  |Store 2|C_date |C_id |Store 3|
--------|----|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-----|-------|
|21.3.21|John|S1     |21.3.21|John  |S2     |21.3.21|John |S3     |
|21.3.21|Per |S1     |null   |null  |null   |null   |null |null   |
|22.3.21|Tom |S1     |null   |null  |null   |22.3.21|Tom  |S3     |
|null   |null|null   |23.3.21|Sam   |S2     |  null |null |null   |
|null   |null|null   |null   |null  |null   |24.3.21|Rob  |S3     |
```

I wish to create a SQL query which checks for date in first column (A_date).

- If it has a date (is *not* null) then keep the date
- If it is null then check if the next date column (B_date) has a date and return that
- If B_date is also null, then check if next date column (C_date) has a date, and return me that date

I wish to end up with a table like this which has a *date* and *id* columns along with the store-columns

```
Date   |ID  |Store 1|Store 2|Store 3|
21.3.21|John|S1     |S2     |S3     |
22.3.21|Tom |S1     |null   |S3     |
23.3.21|Sam |null   |S2     |null   |
24.3.21|Rob |null   |null   |S3     |
```

Comment: How is this table being generated?  I suspect that you can fix the underlying query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [coalesce](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#coalesce):

```
select
  coalesce(a_date, b_date, c_date) as date,
  coalesce(a_id, b_id, c_id) as id,
  store_1,
  store_2,
  store_3
from mytable
```

Comment: nice Sergey, did not know about this and found that it worked. thanks for quick answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have a transaction table with different stores, then you can use conditional aggregation directly on that table:

```
select id, date,
       logical_or(store = 'S1') as store_1,
       logical_or(store = 'S2') as store_2,
       logical_or(store = 'S3') as store_3
from t
group by id, date;
```

This returns booleans for each store.  But it is also easy to change that to the store name if you want that instead.

You can count the number of stores by adding:

```
count(distinct store) as num_stores
```